Почему endl нельзя писать в cin?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> endl; // 13 27 14
    if ( a > b and a > c){
        cout << "Smmalest is " << c;
    }
    return 0;
}


Почему нельзя писать значение в число? Например, cin >> 2;? endl - это что, переменная? Какого типа?

ну например потому что endl это скорее всего "end line", который явно не для потока инпута. а ещё это уже зарезервированная функция..... которая явно ничего в себя не принимает... и нельзя присвоить что-то функции. с таким же успехом можно написать cin >> main - какой будет результат этого?

В cin вообще нельзя ничего писать, только читать\

Потому что a, b, c - переменные, а endl - константа

Это достаточно странный вопрос.
Первое, что вам нужно понять, что такое поток ввода и вывода и как с ним работать. Что делает вообще сin >> a:
Она считывает поток ввода и благодаря перегрузке оператора >> говорит, что запиши мне это в переменную a. Теперь разберемся, что такое std::endl. Это функция, которая очищает поток и переводит курсор на новую строку, через escape последовательность '\n'.
Теперь если мы разберем ваш вопрос, вы спрашиваете почему функция из потока ввода не записывает мои данные в функцию, которая отвечает за отчистку потока вывода и перенос строки? (думаю ответ очевиден, что сам вопрос просто некорректен)
